# Python - Except statement excepting ALL errors

Tags: python

I would expect this code to only catch an EOFError, but instead, it catches ALL exceptions...

```py
    try:
        rpg.data.load("playerdata.dat")
    except EOFError:
        playerdata = rpg.data()
        titleList = ["Start", t.gray30("[DISABLED] Continue"), "Help/Credits", "Exit\n\n" + "  *" + " "* int(stream.width()/tfactor) + t.white("CONTROLS:") + t.gray30("\n\t[ENTER] and [Z] - Confirm Selection\n\tArrow Keys - Move Cursor")]
    else:
        playerdata = rpg.data.load("playerdata.dat")
        titleList = ["Start", "Continue", "Help/Credits", "Exit\n\n" + "  *" + " "* int(stream.width()/tfactor) + t.white("CONTROLS:") + t.gray30("\n\t[ENTER] and [Z] - Confirm Selection\n\tArrow Keys - Move Cursor")]
    finally:
        title_screen = menuClosure(game_title, titleList, delay_ms = 24, tfactor = 6)
```

But it doesn't, because I got a NameError, which was caught:

```
EOFError: Ran out of input

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\capta\OneDrive\Desktop\WHAT\main.py", line 43, in <module>
    titleList = ["Start", t.gray30("[DISABLED] Continue"), "Help/Credits", "Exit\n\n" + "  *" + " "* int(stream.width()/tfactor) + t.white("CONTROLS:") + t.gray30("\n\t[ENTER] and [Z] - Confirm Selection\n\tArrow Keys - Move Cursor")]
NameError: name 'tfactor' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\capta\OneDrive\Desktop\WHAT\main.py", line 48, in <module>
    title_screen = menuClosure(game_title, titleList, delay_ms = 24, tfactor = 6)
NameError: name 'titleList' is not defined
```

Even though I didn't have any other try/except blocks

Comment: It *did* only catch `EOFError`, but while executing the code in `except EOFError` there was *another* exception; a `NameError` which was *not*  caught but caused your program to crash.

Comment: `During handling of the above [EOFError] exception, another exception occurred`

Comment: The first message says `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred`. The exception that occurred was `NameError: name 'tfactor' is not defined`.
So now you know that in the `except` block, you try to access a variable called `tfactor` that has not been declared earlier. It is one of the terms on the`titleList =` line: `int(stream.width()/tfactor)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code didn't catch the NameError. They were thrown inside your try-except-else-finally. It seems you haven't defined tfactor and titleList.